# Controlling Play/Pause of HTML5 audio player when an Iframe's body(Content editable) is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've a Iframe that have Content editable Body, I want to Control the Audio Player While Typing the Text in the Content editable Body my Code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tinymice_textarea_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').keyup(function(event) {
        var audioplayer=document.getElementById('player')
        if(event.keyCode==17)
        {
            $(this).removeClass('hoosp');    
        }
    });
    $('#tinymice_textarea_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').keydown(function(event){
        var audioplayer=document.getElementById('player')
        if(event.keyCode==77)
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass("hoosp")) 
            {
                if (audioplayer.paused) {
                    audioplayer.play();
                }   
                else {
                    audioplayer.pause();
                }
                $(this).removeclass('hoosp');
            }
        }
        if(event.keyCode==17)
        {
            $(this).addClass('hoosp');
        } 
    });
});
```

What's wrong with the above code, I tried it in a simple textarea and it worked well, But in the case of Iframe it doesn't. Please help ..

Comment: A [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) would help.

Comment: Is the player inside or outside the iFrame? Seems to be that you are targeting the wrong document. If the player is above the iFrame then you have to access the parent to stop it.

Comment: Outside the IFrame ..